# 2007 CEWP - Rich Text box - Best way to insert image?

Tags: content-editor-web-part, rich-text

I am a power end user/non-programmer person..so please don't send me in the "custom code" direction--thanks! I need this to be an easy fix! (hopefully) --- I have a CEWP - and am editing it using the rich text box option.  This is a launching pad for my site. At the top of the CEWP I have an image inserted which is a .pdf of a Visio Swim-Lane Flowchart that details the process housed within the site (for the visual people!).  I have the .pdf saved on the site and used the "insert the image" tool to link to it....LOOKS GREAT on my set!---but when I go to the VP's set---to show him the cool stuff I am working on...the image is not really clear...
My thought is that it probably has something to do with the resolution settings on his snazzy big flat screen monitor...and we adjusted that ....but the problem was not fixed! A co-worker has the same issue (and she has the same small but still snazzy flat screen !)
Is there a standard way I need to be doing this--so the image is clear --regardless of monitor size/settings?? Am guessing there is...maybe not a .pdf? Does the Visio image needs to be saved as something else?  Any advice on how to do this is appreciated!
Thanks so much--

Answer (score 3):

I would go with either a .png or a .jpg for the image. To be honest, I'm a little surprised the .pdf worked at all when using it as an image. I think exporting it to one of the other formats (png/jpg) would get you better results.